# Subclass const constructors

Tags: dart, flutter

In order to use `CircularBorderRadius.zero` as a default value in other classes, it must be `const`. Is there any way to make a `const` constructor for `CircularBorderRadius`?

```
class CircularBorderRadius extends BorderRadius {

  static CircularBorderRadius zero = CircularBorderRadius.only();

  CircularBorderRadius.all(double radius)
      : this.only(
    topLeft: radius,
    topRight: radius,
    bottomLeft: radius,
    bottomRight: radius,
  );

  CircularBorderRadius.only({
    double topLeft,
    double topRight,
    double bottomLeft,
    double bottomRight,
  }) : super.only(
      topLeft: topLeft == null ? null : Radius.circular(topLeft),
      topRight: topRight == null ? null : Radius.circular(topRight),
      bottomLeft: bottomLeft == null ? null : Radius.circular(bottomLeft),
      bottomRight: bottomRight == null ? null : Radius.circular(bottomRight));

}
```

**Example**

```
class CustomWidget {
  // ...

  CustomWidget({
    this.borderRadius = CircularBorderRadius.zero, // <—— "error: Default values of an optional parameter must be constant."
  });

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your `CircularBorderRadius.only` const , the optional params should be `const` also, so based on your code you can't.

But you can try something like this:

```
        class CustomWidget {
          // ...

          CustomWidget({
            CircularBorderRadius borderRadius, 
          }): this.borderRadius = borderRadius ?? CircularBorderRadius.zero;

          final CircularBorderRadius borderRadius;
          // ...
        }
```